# OpenLayers.Format.KML write style

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I would like to apply a style to the KML that gets generated from the write() operation of [OpenLayers.Format.KML](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.KML.write). The current style that is on the vector layer does not get exported with this code:

```
function GetKMLFromFeatures = function (features) {
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'maxDepth':10,
        'extractStyles':true,
        'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });

    return format.write(features);
}
```

I would like to add something like this to the KML:

```
<Style id="PolyStyle">
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>ff0000cc</color>
        <fill>0</fill>
        <!-- boolean -->
        <outline>1</outline>
        <!-- boolean -->
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

So that i can specify the fill property. How annoying is this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment i'm just using the javascript replace funtion until a better solution or feature is released/proposed. (I will give you credit if it comes a long)

```
function GetKMLFromFeatures = function (features) {
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'maxDepth':10,
        'extractStyles':true,
        'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });

    var withStyleHeading = format.write(features).replace(/<Folder>/g, '<Folder>' + kmlStyle);
    var withEverything = withStyleHeading.replace(/lacemark><name>/g, 'lacemark><styleUrl>#PolyStyle</styleUrl><name>');

    return withEverything;
}
```